# Resizing img to 100% inside td

Tags: html, css, html-email

I want to set the image size to 100% inside of td.

```html
<table style="width:100%; max-width:960px; margin:auto;">
  <tr style="width:100%;">
 <td background="http://source/bg.png"> 
          <img src="http://source/logo.png" style="margin-left:35%;" />
   <h1 style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;"> Some text on top of bg-image inside a td</a></h1>
 </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

So I have a big td with bg-image and a logo on top of it with some text.I am doing css all in-line to be able to send html email.

The problem is that the image has it's natural size, and doesn't resize to 100% to fit the td size.

Comment: your 'run code snippet' didn't work..

Comment: @saina, of course, i deleted the proper links

Comment: Please review the available answers, if you need more help do feel free to ask

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, emails are a pain when it comes to CSS / HTML Standards... Google will help you here.. In general.. Your best testing this with outlook/hotmail/gmail.. Outlook is one of the worse for supporting HTML Emails.

As for the code, have a look at this example instead: http://jsfiddle.net/82bd2fyh/

```
<table style="width:100%; max-width:960px; margin:auto;">
  <tr style="width:100%;">
    <td style="background-size:100% 100%; background-image:url('http://placehold.it/550x550');">    
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100/09f/fff.png" style="margin-left:35%;" />
      <h1 style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;"> Some text on top of bg-image inside a td</a></h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please note though, background-size is only supported in CSS3, IE9+..
Otherwise another option is to use a normal image tag and stretch that to 100% then position with a z-index your content / a div over top of it.

Email Support Guide Line: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

The above is also under the assumption you are talking about the background image and not the logo / img tag.

If you mean your img tag, then simply apply a style to it.. But do believe you mean your TD background image

Comment: Just checking the CSS guide. If Position isn't supported in Outlook then how does z-index work? Or am I missing something?!

Answer (score 1):

Building on Mayem's answer, which is 100% right in almost all email clients, I wanted to add a bit more to it. This will not work in Outlook at all and has potential for issues with Gmail app.

1.) Outlook almost always forces actual size of the image, regardless of CSS or HTML resizing (size is also based on the PPI setting on your computer) so it is always best to size your images to fit what you want them to display at in Outlook and then control size for all other clients.

2.) Outlook does not support background image, so you will need to use VML to mimic this for outook - best place for that is http://backgrounds.cm/. It will do most of the work for you.

3.) Gmail does not read stylesheets, so the code will likely lead to a deformed version when displayed on gmail app - this is something you will need to work on from a design/layout perspective

4.) Margin-left and most of the code on the overlay content needs work for email HTML as it is not supported on many email clients.

See below code that is built from Mayhem's answer with some tweaks and the Outlook conditional VML added in.

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%; max-width:960px; margin:0 auto;">
  <tr>
    <td background="http://placehold.it/960x550" width="960" height="550" style="background-size:auto 100%; background-image:url('http://placehold.it/960x550');">    
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:960px;height:550px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://placehold.it/960x550"  />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
  <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100/09f/fff.png" style="margin-left:35%;" />

      <h1 style="text-align:center;"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;"> Some text on top of bg-image inside a td</a></h1>
  </div>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
</td>  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply change

```
<img src="http://source/logo.png" style="margin-left:35%;" />
```

to

```
<img src="http://source/logo.png" style="width:100%;margin-left:35%;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A more correct solution is to change

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/100/09f/fff.png" style="margin-left:35%;" />
```

to

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/100/09f/fff.png" style="width:65%;margin-left:35%;" />
```

Comment: No need to double post, just use your own answer and other both solutions in the same response/answer.